# Cordova remote ios build fail

Tags: ios, visual-studio, cordova, phonegap-build, remote-debugging

I am trying to make a remote ios build for my one of my cordova apps, and I am always getting this error

```
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    Ld build/emulator/MyApp\ HR.app/MyApp\ HR normal i386
    (1 failure)
Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/admin/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/368/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,-project,MyApp HR.xcodeproj,ARCHS=i386,-target,MyApp HR,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,build,VALID_ARCHS=i386,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/admin/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/368/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/admin/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/368/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

Command finished with error code 2: /Users/admin/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/368/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build --debug
ERROR building one of the platforms : error : /Users/admin/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/368/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2

You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
Failed to build app for buildNumber 368: /Users/admin/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/368/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2

Error : Remote build error from the build server Build failed with error /Users/admin/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/368/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build: Command failed with exit code 2: {1}
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I don't know why, however I am able to build other apps successfully, [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/rb46oy7bq6lqxo5/corodva%20build%20log.txt?dl=0) is my full log

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you solve it? Having the same problem

Comment: @Namirna, I am also getting same error. Have you solved?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, usually it happened because provisioning profile is not set up properly. 
- https://dpogue.ca/articles/cordova-xcode8.html, everything you need is configure the build.json file
my file is:

```
{
  "ios": {
    "debug": {
      "developmentTeam": "XXXXXXXXXX",
      "provisioningProfile": "ProfileName"
    },
    "release": {
      "codeSignIdentity": "XXXXXXXx",
      "developmentTeam": "XXXXX",
      "packageType": "ad-hoc",
      "provisioningProfile": "ProfileName"
    }
  }
}
```

- anyway right now I got the 72 error,
  xcrun: error: unable to find utility "PackageApplication", not a developer tool or in PATH