# Remote Build problems using Visual Studio 2017. Error code 65

Tags: ios, cordova, ios-simulator, visual-studio-2017

Our project is failing to run on iOS simulator in the new Visual Studio. This is the following error I get:

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Remote build error from the build server http://<MY_IP>:3000/cordova - Build failed with error Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args: -xcconfig,/Users/developer/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/46767/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build-release.xcconfig,-workspace,Announce.xcworkspace,-scheme,Announce,-configuration,Release,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS Simulator,name=iPhone 5s,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Users/developer/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/46767/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Users/developer/.taco_home/remote-builds/taco-remote/builds/46767/cordovaApp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch   ApbClient       1
```

It might have to do with the Cordova version. On new VS2017 the default Cordova version is 6.3.1 or Global Cordova 6.5.0. On VS2015 we were using Cordova 5.4.1.

Any ideas on what is causing this error? I have tried a bunch of things suggested in old StackOverflow questions but none of it seems to work. It was working fine on 2015, we have development team and everything set up. Could it be something I need to do on xCode? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: It may be because your xcode version on the remote server needs to be upgraded to support the new iOS platform in Cordova 6.3.1. can you try updating it?

Answer (score 0):

since xcode 8 they change the deploy politics, not sure it related to emulators but with actual device I had the same issue. It happened because provisioning profile is not set up properly. 
- https://dpogue.ca/articles/cordova-xcode8.html, everything you need is configure the build.json file
my file is:

```
{
  "ios": {
    "debug": {
      "developmentTeam": "XXXXXXXXXX",
      "provisioningProfile": "ProfileName"
    },
    "release": {
      "codeSignIdentity": "XXXXXXXx",
      "developmentTeam": "XXXXX",
      "packageType": "ad-hoc",
      "provisioningProfile": "ProfileName"
    }
  }
}
```

- anyway right now I got the 72 error,
  xcrun: error: unable to find utility "PackageApplication", not a developer tool or in PATH

Comment: I have found that you have reposted the same answer posted on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34391721/cordova-remote-ios-build-fail/43891343#43891343 Please avoid this situation.